# Run c# .NET Program from network share

Tags: c#, networking, caspol

got a interesting problem. I placed a c# .net .exe file on a network share. If i try to

```
Start->Run: \\hostname\test.exe
```

my software starts properly and everything is working.

We also have a DNS Alias set for this computer, so if I try to run my program by:

```
Start->Run: \\mydnsalias\test.exe
```

My programm will cause an error message: "**test has encountered a problem and needs to close...**"

On client .net 2.0, 3.0, 3.5sp1 is installed. There is a full trust caspol for the network share (set with dnsalias).

Comment: Is the caspol hack applied to both hostname and mydnsalias?

Comment: What's the error? It should be in the more details part of the encountered a problem dialog.

Comment: No, there is only "test has encountered a problem and needs to close..." as headline and below "If you have not saved your work yet, ... blahblah.." No additional message. Cause this in on a terminalserver, i cant give you information about eventlog.

Comment: Log the exception, and if it is the security exception, log all the properties of it, it should tell you what zone you need to specify the security settings for.

Comment: @Hans99 - re "only to dnsalias"; if you mean "mydnsalias", then it **shouldn't** work from \\hostname\test.exe. Are you sure there isn't a second caspol hack somewhere? Of course, the other option is that the caspol hack you've **added** for "mydnsalias" is simply wrong.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: This is my caspol machine entry: 1.6.  Url - \\mydnsalias\\*: FullTrust (Exclusive)

Comment: @Lasse: Howto log this exception? It is thrown before my software really starts?!

Comment: You can try just outputting it to the console to begin with. And no, if there is an exception, your program has started.

Answer (score 4):

Caspol "tweaks" are a bit of a pain to deploy robustly. IMO, the best way to run an exe off the network is in a way that the core framework isn't going to object to in the first place.

Since you have 3.5 SP1, one *simple* way is to map the share to a drive. IIRC, with this service pack, "j:\test.exe" will be trusted, even though "j:" is mapped to "\hostname", and "\hostname\test.exe" might **not** be trusted.

The other approach is ClickOnce; you publish to the network share and run "test.application" instead. This also gives you options like local-copy with auto-update, file extension handling, etc.

Comment: If i map the share (by dnsalias) i get the same error message. Its a problem with dnsalias only. If i use \\hostname everythign works fine, but as soon as i use \\mydnsalias it causes the error... SO i think this is no caspol failure.

Comment: ClickOnce is not an opinion for me in this case.