# My WPF C# Exe when shared over network and accessed with drive letter works but with just the shared drive does not

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, network-shares, hosted-app

My executable developed on C#, WPF is shared on network. 
When I input this and run, \192.168.0.15\D$\App\WinApp.exe the application kicks off, but when I just do \192.168.0.15\App\WinApp.exe the application does not kicks off. I have logger implementation in the App() constructor but it does not even reach that point. 
On the event viewer, got exception code 0xc0000005

Answer (score 1):

`0xc0000005` reads a security issue, in fact you cannot run .Net code from a network share unless you explicitly allow for it. I assume that the first invocation is not recognized as a remote share (maybe it is the same machine).

You have many options to solve this:

1. Avoiding the share path (e.g. [Run c# .NET Program from network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341502/run-c-sharp-net-program-from-network-share))
2. Tweaking the security of all client machines (e.g. [run c# app from network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023021/run-c-sharp-app-from-network-share))
3. Publish the program on an HTTP server and use ClickOnce